# Express result of calculation in terms of Gamma functions only

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, series-expansion

I would like to to express the result of my integration just in terms of Gamma functions. The following integral is at hand:

$$
\int_0^1dz\int_0^1dy(z(1-z))^{-\epsilon}(1-y)^{1-2\epsilon}y^{-1-\epsilon}(z(1-z)-2)
$$

yielding the result with mathematica

$$
\frac{\sqrt{\pi}2^{2\epsilon-3}(7\epsilon-11)\Gamma(2-2\epsilon)\Gamma(1-\epsilon)\Gamma(-\epsilon)}{\Gamma(2-3\epsilon)\Gamma(\frac{5}{2}-\epsilon)},
$$

where one can rewrite the $\sqrt{\pi}2^{2\epsilon-3}$ in terms of Gamma functions. By employing

```
Series[%, {\[Epsilon], 0, 0}]
```

we obtain

$$
\frac{11}{6\epsilon}+\frac{1}{6}\left(4+11\gamma+22\log(2)+11\psi^{(0)}\left(\frac{5}{2}\right)\right)+\mathcal{O}(\epsilon^1).
$$

Is it possible to express the result of the integration in terms of Gamma functions or to express the last line as $\frac{11}{6\epsilon}+\frac{50}{9}+\mathcal{O}(\epsilon^1)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`FullSimplify`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullSimplify.html) with [`Series`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Series.html)

```
(int = Assuming[Re[ϵ] < 1, Integrate[
    (z (1 - z))^-ϵ (1 - y)^(1 - 2 ϵ) y^(-1 - ϵ) (z (1 - z) - 2), 
    {z, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}] // Simplify]) // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

```
Series[int, {ϵ, 0, 0}] // FullSimplify
```

[image]

```
Series[int, {ϵ, 0, 1}] // FullSimplify
```

[image]

**EDIT:** Note that since

```
Gamma[1/2]
```

[image]

then

```
rule = Gamma[1/2] -> 8/15*Inactive[Gamma][7/2]
```

[image]

```
(int2 = int /. rule) // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

```
int == int2 // Activate

(* True *)
```